# Getting "argument:2 <class Type Error> Wrong type " error while starting SQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have Downloaded the Mysql server. But when I am starting the server it's giving me this error :
argument:2  Wrong type

I have seen for this error on online resources but I was unable to find any.
Later as MySQl was not present in the Windows Services so I have installed it by running this command in cmd:
Mysqld -- Install

Note:
I am using Mysql of Oracle
Using Windows 10 for Installing.

I only want to start myserver server.
[Command i used for Getting MySQL in Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYsUO.png)

[Error which I am getting on MySQL workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BT435.png)

Do let me know what should be done to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install mysql server and mysql workbench after uninstalling once!...It worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue. i solved it by running "MySQL Installer - Community", which allowed me to setup the service again.